# How to ignore a polymorph readable type, while reading?

Tags: haskell

I have a problem similar to:

```
data Foo a = Foo { myInt :: Integer, myValue :: a } deriving Read

bar :: String -> Integer
bar = myInt . read

main = print $ bar stringWithFooOfa
```

i don't want to use something like `read . (!!1) . words`, if i don't need to.

Comment: The problem is that `bar` doesn't have enough information to know how to read the string into a `Foo a` since it doesn't know what `a` is.  Without knowing what `a` is, it doesn't know which instance of `Read` to use.  If you know define bar to be `bar str = (myInt foo, myValue foo) where foo = read str`, then it'll compile just fine.  Unfortunately, you can't create another function `barInt = fst . bar` because it'll just run into the same problem.  I'd suggest staying away from functions like that, as convenient as they sound.

Comment: You're going to have to explicitly state what `a` is. Each `a` has a different parser and if `a` isn't readable than there isn't even a read instance for `Foo`.

Answer (score 1):

Add a type annotation to `read`. As commenters suggested, Haskell has no way of knowing what you're trying to read since you immediately turn it into an `Int`. To be more clear, consider this example:

```
data Foo a  = Foo { myInt  :: Integer, myValue  :: a } deriving Read
data Foo2 a = Foo { myInt2 :: Integer                } deriving Read

bar :: String -> Integer
bar = myInt . read
```

Now there are two very different behaviors for `bar` possible and it's hard to know which is correct.

To tell Haskell which one you want, use an inline annotation around `read`:

```
bar :: String -> Integer
bar = myInt . (read :: String -> Foo ())
```

Notice that I pick an `a`, too. Otherwise, we'll be in the same boat as above but just with `a` instead of `Foo`.